# Returning the row with the most recent timestamp from each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table (Postgres 9.3) defined as follows:

```
 CREATE TABLE tsrs (
     id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
     customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES customers,
     timestamp TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
     licensekeys_checksum VARCHAR(32));
```

The pertinent details here are the `customer_id`, the `timestamp`, and the `licensekeys_checksum`. There can be multiple entries with the same `customer_id`, some of those may have matching `licensekey_checksum` entries, and some may be different. There will never be rows with equal checksum and equal timestamps.

I want to return a table containing 1 row for each group of rows with matching `licensekeys_checksum` entries. The row returned for each group should be the one with the newest / most recent timestamp.

Sample Input:

```
1, 2, 2014-08-21 16:03:35, 3FF2561A
2, 2, 2014-08-22 10:00:41, 3FF2561A
2, 2, 2014-06-10 10:00:41, 081AB3CA
3, 5, 2014-02-01 12:03:23, 299AFF90
4, 5, 2013-12-13 08:14:26, 299AFF90
5, 6, 2013-09-09 18:21:53, 49FFA891
```

Desired Output:

```
2, 2, 2014-08-22 10:00:41, 3FF2561A
2, 2, 2014-06-10 10:00:41, 081AB3CA
3, 5, 2014-02-01 12:03:23, 299AFF90
5, 6, 2013-09-09 18:21:53, 49FFA891
```

I have managed to piece together a query based on the comments below, and hours of searching on the internet. :)

```
select * from tsrs
inner join (
   select licensekeys_checksum, max(timestamp) as mts
   from tsrs
   group by licensekeys_checksum
   ) x on x.licensekeys_checksum = tsrs.licensekeys_checksum
      and x.mts = tsrs.timestamp;
```

It seems to work, but I am unsure. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Use GROUP BY and MAX.

Comment: Are there records with equal checksum **and** equal timestamps ? (BTW: `timestamp` is a bad name for a column)

Comment: @joop There will never be records with equal checksum and equal timestamps.  Why is timestamp a bad name for a column? I'm quite new to all this, so would appreciate any knowledge you have to give :)

Comment: Because it is also the name of a data type. This could confuse parsers, frameworks, or people.

Comment: TIMESTAMP is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, so it won't work with many dbms products - unless you double quote it, as "timestamp". (And since it's a reserved word, it may also be reserved in a future version of  postgresql, then your applications will no longer work.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query in the question should perform better than the queries in the (previously) accepted answer. Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

`DISTINCT ON` is typically simpler and faster:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (licensekeys_checksum) *
FROM   tsrs
ORDER  BY licensekeys_checksum, timestamp DESC NULLS LAST;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=376cdaf9d039b6f45ae2afbe7aa7602c)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2f1fc/1)</sub>

Detailed explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select * 
from tsrs
where (timestamp,licensekeys_checksum) in (
                                          select max(timestamp)
                                                ,licensekeys_checksum
                                          from tsrs 
                                          group by licensekeys_checksum)
```

[**>SqlFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b73ce/1/0)

or

```
with cte as (
            select id
                   ,customer_id
                   ,timestamp
                   ,licensekeys_checksum
                   ,row_number () over (partition by  licensekeys_checksum  ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as rk
            from  tsrs)
select  id
       ,customer_id
       ,timestamp
       ,licensekeys_checksum  
from cte where rk=1 order by id
```

[**>SqlFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b73ce/2/0)

---

Reference  : [**Window Functions**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html), [**row_number()**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html), and [**CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html)

Comment: This returns the same results as my query above, but is far more understandable (for me at least :). I will use this version instead. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative deduplication, using `NOT EXISTS(...)`

```
SELECT *
FROM tsrs t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tsrs x
    WHERE x.customer_id = t.customer_id                  -- same customer
    AND x.licensekeys_checksum = t.licensekeys_checksum  -- same checksum
    AND x.ztimestamp > t.ztimestamp                      -- but more recent
    );
```